# React JS, object of components have access to each other. Why is this working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object

I was playing around with some components, and I had a few components in a basic javascript object, when I realised that I was (for some unknown reason) able to reference them between each other.

As far as I'm aware this shouldn't really be possible. Can anyone provide any insight as to why this works?

```
export const Main = () => {
    return (
        <Components.Layout/>
    )
}

const Components = {
    Layout: () => {
        return (<Components.SectionA/>)
    },
    SectionA: () => {
        return (<Components.SectionB/>)
    },
    SectionB: () => {
        return (<p>Hello There</p>)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what exactly you find surprising here.

Comment: Or what is specific to React. You have an object in scope, you can access its properties.

Comment: Object don't have an inherent order. So it doesn't matter if you reference a property on line 1 and define the property on line 2; the entire object will be loaded into memory, so all properties you've defined will exist at runtime.

Comment: Is this the same thing that you find surprising? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwJZhgXhgbwFAxgcwFMoARBKBALhgAoBKdAPlsxgBNyqYBGAJgGYYAXzoAaXDABmIENXpN4yMADoipTvXFDs2UJBAAbQsoMh8NRCmXSQ9BgHp7Wdp2p9B2oA If so, this has nothing to with react.

Comment: I guess it isn't specific to react, that is just the context that I came across it. My understanding was always that properties within an object cannot access each other.

Comment: Emiel Zuubier has answered the question. I'm not sure where I got the idea that the properties would not be able to access each other.

Comment: If you tried to access them directly (ie. `const obj = { a: 1, b: obj.a };`) then your assumption would be correct because `obj` does not yet exist. But because you are assigning your properties as methods by the time each method is called `obj` exists in scope. But the standard way to do this is to access `this` (not in an arrow function) to avoid the reference being lost should a reference of the original object try to access the property after the original is destroyed.

Comment: @pilchard that fully explains the situation and in hindsight should have been obvious. Thank you.